# Proper use of Could/Should/Would

Tags: grammaticality

Are the following sentences correct?

1) How would that be?

2) How should that be?

3) How could that be?

If the above sentences are correct, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and third sentences are correct:

'How would that be?' is more or less equivalent to 'Would that be acceptable?'

'How could that be?' is more or less equivalent to 'How is that possible?'

I am less certain of the second sentence as I have not heard nor read it. It would be more likely that you would hear or read, 'How should **it** be?' as an shorthand for 'How should it be done?'. This would be in response to something like 'That wasn't done correctly'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question in this context: what does the following sentence mean: "How will this be?"